# How i can work with sockets when app in background or was killed?

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin, background

I have socket connection with backend and fetch some data from here. All is well, but when app go to background and back to foreground again, most always app lost socket connection. I don't use any services or other things(with long scope) for connection and i guess system just kill my app with all connectivity inside. Please advise reliable solution for that.

**Update:**
I don't know it's great solution or not, but i tried to use bounded services. Just try keep connection all time.
Maybe somebody have most nice idea?

Comment: Over what timescale?  If you need it for a minute or two, a Service.  If its for a longer time, a foreground Service.  If its for a really long time, you need to rearchitect-  you cannot depend on your app staying resident in the background on Android.

Comment: @GabeSechan, I just need it when ui is visible, not more.

Comment: Your current code would be helpful, how do you handle connection in activity right now? It should not break connection when going back/foreground.

Comment: If you're talking about the app going to the background and foreground, then you need more than just when the UI is visible.  If you mean only the Activity goes tot he background not the whole app (like when you launch another activity), then a Service will do that.  If you mean when the full app does, a foreground Service will work for a while, but not if the OS feels the need for more resources.